# JNDI Look Up Exception - Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost and discovery failed with error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi

I'm talking about a JAVA EJB-WEB APP project from my college. I tried anything so far to fix this issue before I post it.

I run it with Debug mode, the line that I get this is exception:

```
QueueConnectionFactory f = (QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
```

I'm trying to lookup the JNDI when I get this terrible exception.
I don't know why. I've tried to change the PORT, change the PROVIDER_URL to a lot of options and still, it doesn't work. I get the same error every time.

This is the Class - BusinessDelegate where is the JNDI gets is properties:

```
public class BusinessDelegate {
    private QueueSession qsession;
    private QueueSender qsender;
    private IncomeService incomeService;

    public BusinessDelegate(){
        // Prepare initial context

//      Hashtable<String,String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String,String>();
        Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
//      jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"localhost");
//      jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http://0.0.0.0");
//      jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        try
        {
            // Set initial context
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
            // Set the rest of connection properties
            QueueConnectionFactory f = (QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            Queue q = (Queue)ctx.lookup("queue/couponQueue");
            incomeService = (IncomeService)ctx.lookup("incomeService/local");
            QueueConnection qcon = f.createQueueConnection();
            qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            qsender = qsession.createSender(q);
            ctx.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            // for testing..
            System.out.println("Something went wrong! in + [" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "] Class-Construrctor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public synchronized void storeIncome(Income i){
        try{
            qsender.send(qsession.createObjectMessage(i));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Income persistance failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Collection<Income> viewAllIncome(){
        return incomeService.viewAllIncome();
    }

    public Collection<Income> viewIncomeByCompany(long id){
        return incomeService.viewIncomeByCompany(id);
    }

    public Collection<Income> viewIncomeByCustomer(long id){
        return incomeService.viewIncomeByCustomer(id);
    }
}
```

I can give you full access to the project in GitHub if it's necessary.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please check [ask] for tips on how to get the most out of this site.  Also it's best to try and create a [mcve] that someone can repeat without having to look at a full repository of code, anything more is a bit beyond the scope of a QA site like SO.

Comment: I check this before, thanks.
or somthing is not right with my question>?

Comment: The important part in this case is the [mcve].  Two paste links and a large block of code is difficult to interpret as minimal :)